What function do the data annotations "ForeignKey", "InverseProperty" and "Required" have on a EF Core database first?
Do the ForeignKey, InverseProperty and Required attributes in EF Core have any real function in a database-first approach?
I know that in a code-first they instruct EF Core how to build columns and relationships. But if I have an existing database and set up my context and classes from it, would those attributes help EF Core generate better queries or anything?
If we ignore the readability or self-documenting aspect, would there be ANY benefit of using those attributes in database first?

They allow EF to detect errors in your data model before creating and sending queries to the database. For instance, a required property that is missing would be an error and without the attributes you would not catch that until you received an error back from the database after a failure on the DB side. By the same token, at least in theory, developers have more information while writing and testing code and that can help produce better code with less time wasted.

@topsail, what about the foreign key and inverse property? Does EF Core do checks for them, too?

Foreign keys I think so, for the same reasons. Inverse properties yes - see properly https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/data-annotation-attributes/inverseproperty-attribute

I'm not a huge fan of EF myself, but it seems to me if you are going to use it and want to do so for more reasons that "its the easiest thing I can do (?) and I just want to do the minimum that works" ... then you should have an EF model that is an accurate representation, insofar as possible, of your database model.

EF follows convention by default, so if your entity mirrors your schema and your navigation properties are named the same as the type of the entity they point at, EF will be more than happy to work things out.
A common example of where you would want to use [ForeignKey]
public class Order
{
    // ...

    public int CreatedById { get; set; }
    public int LastModifiedById { get; set; }

    public virtual User CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public virtual User LastModifiedBy { get; set; }
}

Most writing this the first time would expect it to work. Whether you use shadow properties or FK properties, by convention, EF would be looking for, and complain about something like a missing UserId and UserId1 column for these two navigation properties. Convention is on the navigation property Type rather than the name. For the above to work you need to tell EF which FK the relationship should use.
[ForeignKey(nameof(CreatedById)]
public virtual User CreatedBy { get; set; }
[ForeignKey(nameof(LastModifiedById)]
public virtual User LastModifiedBy { get; set; }

The [ForeignKey] attribute is also useful for defining shadow properties in the same way.
InverseProperty is merely the attribute alternative for defining bi-directional references rather than A.HasMany(a => a.Bs).WithOne(b => b.A));
An example of this is say for whatever reason we wanted the User entity to have a collection of Orders they created.. How do we pair up User.MyOrders to Order.CreatedBy vs. Order.LastModifiedBy? [InverseAttribute].
[ForeignKey(nameof(CreatedById)]
[InverseProperty("MyOrders")] // User.MyOrders
public virtual User CreatedBy { get; set; }
[ForeignKey(nameof(LastModifiedById)]
public virtual User LastModifiedBy { get; set; }

Personally though for navigation properties I use fluent configuration with IEntityTypeConfiguration<TEntity>. This is compile-time safe where renaming a property can break the magic string attributes.
